# find triangle in a complete graph having minimum edge weight sum

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Given a complete undirected graph $G(V, E)$, with $n$ vertices and every edge having a positive weight $E_{ij} \gt 0$.

How can one efficiently find a triangle/three vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3$ such that the sum of edges between them is minimum?

$\arg\min_{i, j, k} E_{ij}+E_{ik} + E_{jk}, s.t. i\neq j \neq k$

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether vertex $i$ is selected, and for $(i,j)\in E$, let $y_{i,j}$ represent $x_i x_j$.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{(i,j)\in E} E_{i,j} y_{i,j}$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= 3 \tag1 \\
x_i + x_j - 1 &\le y_{i,j} &&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$} \tag2 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects three vertices.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $(x_i \land x_j) \implies y_{i,j}$.

Comment: Thanks! I’m wondering if there is more graph based approach, as my goal is to find the minimum among a few graphs.